# Send params activity when use "Parameters for notification messaging by platform GCM"(android)

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

Sorry for my english. I use **GCM** for notification, server create json use standart **GCM** form [this](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json). **Problem**: when app is open and i have notification, evrithing fine all intent and put extra work good. But when app is closed, and i get notification, when i click from this notification open standart activity in app.(not activity what i set)  This is due to the fact that, android if app is closed created own notification and he dont know about enother intent and activity, he open standart activity in app. The solution to this problem need send from server `click_action`, and in manifest need do something like this:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="OPEN_ACTIVITY_1" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

**Qestion:** how i cant use `putExtra` when android create own push?(not use my class for notification)

**UPD:**
class create notification(problem not here):

```
public class GcmMessageHandler extends GcmListenerService {

    static int count = 0;

     @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
String name = notification.getString("title");
String message = notification.getString("body");

 Resources res = ctx.getResources();
             PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
             PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");
             wl.acquire(15000);

             NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
             mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx);

             mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification); 
             mBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.icon));

             mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000});
             mBuilder.setTicker(name + ":" + message);
             mBuilder.setContentText(message);
             mBuilder.setContentTitle(name);
             mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
             mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
             mBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message));


            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


             PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                     PendingIntent.getActivity(
                            ctx,
                            count,
                             i,
                             PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


            mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
            NotificationManager myNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                     ctx.getSystemService(ctx.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

             myNotificationManager.notify(count, mBuilder.build());
}

}
```

**UPD** Manifest(when i use permission and GCM)

```
<!-- GCM -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

         <permission android:name="myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />
        <uses-permission android:name="myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
        <!-- GCM END -->



     <!-- GCM -->
     <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="myapp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="push.GcmMessageHandler"  
       android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> 

    <!-- GCM -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this one to send notification

```
private void sendNotification(String from, String message) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("name", from);
        bundle.putString("message", message);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("INFO", bundle);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(from)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }
```

And don't forget to add WAKE_LOCK permission in Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: Thanks for yout answer! I update my qestion, my class for push work fine only app is open, when app is closed class `Activity2.class` not open because i think gcm generated own notification when app is closed. And gcm not see activity and intent and putExtra. I dont know how use `putExtra` when app is closed

Comment: Did you add that permission above, it will help your app receive notification although it not run.

Comment: if it still not OK. please post full of code from your AndroidManifest.xml in your question.

Comment: Yes, i have this permission, but it not work.I have big maniset, i add only permission and GCM, but if it importand add all manifet, i can do this

Comment: Sorry but I cannot find anything wrong.. I'm doing chat app with GCM but I'm using `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` not `GcmListenerService`